# IF statement XML/XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got code like below, I want to add class to dictionary__value_txt when @name = "Width", it works, but it works for every span with class dictionary__value_txt, even when @name != "Width".
Do You have any ideas what is wrong ?

```
<xsl:for-each select="values/value">
<span class="dictionary__value_txt">
<xsl:if test="/shop/page/projector/product/dictionary/items/item/@name = 'Width'">
                      <xsl:attribute name="class"> dictionary__value_txt lens_width </xsl:attribute> 
                      </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</span>
```

I tried to do something with path in if, but no results.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: Without a [mcve] we can only guess. My guess would be that you are using an absolute path where a relative path is needed. Your test will return true if there is at least one `name` attribute whose value is "Width" in the entire XML document, regardless of the current context.

Comment: BTW, it's not likely that "it works" when you have an attribute on the end-tag of `xsl:for-each`.

Comment: Yes, the problem was with absolute path. Thanks !